# Angularjs and automatically generated SELECT tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bit of a problem, I have an API that provides me with products, and each product has multiple options, like so :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Product 1 all options",
                "price": 2000
            }, {
                "name": "Product 1 no option",
                "price": 1400
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Product 2 all options",
                "price": 3000
            }, {
                "name": "Product 2 no option",
                "price": 1900
            }
        ]
    }];
```

Now I present it as so :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option
                    ng-repeat="option in product.options"
                    data-price="{{ option.price }}">{{ option.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE SELECTED option.price +/- VAT</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now as you may notice, the `<select>` tag itself is inside a `ng-repeat`, so it can be infinitely repeated, depending on the number of products I have; I can't bind the `select` to any `ng-model` because I may accidentally bind many `<select>`'s to the same model.

Now for each `<select>`, I have to display the price +/- a VAT in the third `<td>`, that corresponds to the selected option. Is there any way of doing that with angularjs? I don't want to go plain JS/jQuery.

Comment: Use `ng-options` and `ng-model` in the select element. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **product** variable as the model for the select. When the value changes it will also be updated outside the select as well.

An example would be:

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <input ng-model="product">
    <div>{{product}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can find a working plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/C2379mUbeq44lXTmLZCj?p=preview).

A working example using your data. It's making a new field in your product called **selectedPrice** just to store the selected option.

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{
    "name": "Product 1",
    "options": [{
      "name": "Product 1 all options",
      "price": 2000
    }, {
      "name": "Product 1 no option",
      "price": 1400
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "options": [{
      "name": "Product 2 all options",
      "price": 3000
    }, {
      "name": "Product 2 no option",
      "price": 1900
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="product.selectedPrice">
          <option ng-repeat="option in product.options" value="{{ option.price }}">{{ option.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>{{product.selectedPrice}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A working example of that can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxMqOZYpaNjGmptV7T7x?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of it that way :)

Comment: @Shotgun I would recommend using the ng-options directive as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @toskv you can also avoid option tag altogether.

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
  <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="product.selectedPrice" ng-options="option.price as option.name for option in product.options track by option.name">
       </select>
    </td>
  <td>{{product.selectedPrice}}</td>
</tr>
```

see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/q4eBj7vlablB8pC1EKyj?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this version :)